# How to limit fraud, abuse and/or spam of public APIs without reCpatcha?

Tags: spam-prevention

We provide an external JS-script to our partners, that they include in their e-commerce website. Basically, they call a function whenever a purchased has been made so we can record conversions of purchases referred by us and also change the state of the purchased item (items are set as purchased).

However, because our script is executed on the client side (for the sake of making the implementation simple for our partners), they can be used by an attacker to spam the platform with unreal requests. Enforcing a private key policy for every request to ensure they're legitimate requests is useless because they'll be exposed to the public anyway.

I don't think that ReCaptcha or invisible captcha would be an option, since the request has to be made as quick as possible and we use a pixel image to send the request. So, we were wondering how do services like Google Analytics, Google AdSense etc. detect and prevent spam requests or requests that are not coming from a real user.

We do understand that because the implementation is client-side only, there's no 100% prevention. We just hope that we could make it difficult enough that it doesn't worth the time and effort of an attacker.

So, what are possible solutions to ensure request made to the API are a result of an actual action made by a real user?

Comment: Check out Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf) book. He discusses several ways to approach the problem.